# CORS AWS API-Gateway with Authentication Angular2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda

my AWS API-Gateway is configured as Lambda Proxy. In Lambda i added the following Headers:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'
```

First, everythink works fine with it. Now i added an Authorizer with CognitoUserPool and i get the following Error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I think the problem is, that with Authentication my Lambdafunction is not invoked and so no Headers were set. I call the Endpoint from an Angular2 Application with

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'authtoken');
http.get('address...', headers);
```

But the headers were not set/append to the request because of any CORS-reasons i think.

Anyone an idea how can i solve this?

P.S.: I tried the "Enable Cors" feature of API-Gateway but that does not work.

Edit: I also have a "OPTIONS" Method in Gateway with Authentication, that responds with the Headers above.

Greetings

Comment: I know it's trivial but I have to ask: Did you deploy your API after enabling CORS to reflect those changes?

Comment: Yes I did deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem. It was not caused by API-Gateway. Problem was this code:

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'authtoken');
http.get('address...', headers);
```

The "get" needs a "RequestOptions"-object. It has to be:

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'authtoken');
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
http.get('address...', options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your Lambda Proxy function mapping to the `ANY` HTTP method type? If so, it may be attempting to perform authentication on the pre-flight (`OPTIONS`) request. If this is the case, try mapping your proxy function to `POST`, `GET`, etc. specifically.

Comment: No, it is specially mapped to every Function. Not with the Any-Method.